# PHP 7.0.9/NGINX 1.11.3/Magento 2.0 Setup gives blank page

Tags: magento2, installation, server-setup, php-7

This is my first time posting here and I am hoping someone can help me out, I am a little stumped.

We have a Linux CentOS 7 server with PHP 7.0.9 and NGINX 1.11.3 installed.

We are trying to install Magento 2.0 but we keep getting a blank page when going to the setup.

We are not seeing an errors in the NGINX on PHP logs and the php info page renders correctly.

Please let me know what other information to provide.

Thank You.

Comment: check your http response code, is it `200 OK` or `500` or `503`  is there anything in browser console?

Comment: @MagenX I don't see anything in the console.

Comment: @MagenX I am getting a 200 response. There is a grey bar at the top of the page and that is all.

Comment: @MagenX In the Net tab in FF, I see a few 404s (http://SITENAME/setup/index.php/navigation, etc).

Comment: Magento 2.0 is dead, long live Magento 2.0... Unless you're past 2.0.5 or wherever the 9.8 earthquakes got patched.

Comment: I just install magento2.1.4 with php7.0.6  with php-fpm + nginx1.11.3 successfully. After compiling all mentioned with their dependencies. Please first try to install all dependent modules of PHP mentioned http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html and and also do share your nginx.conf

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue.
I have 2 ways to resolve this problem:

1. Installation via command line.
   Read more at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html
2. Change config of PHP-FPM and Nginx.

> Here are some possible solutions:
>
> 1. In your php-fpm www.conf set `security.limit_extensions` to `.php` or `.php5` or whatever suits your environment. For some users, completely removing all values or setting it to `FALSE` was the only way to get it working.
> 2. In your nginx config file set `fastcgi_pass` to your socket address (e.g. `unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;`) instead of your server address and port.
> 3. Check your `SCRIPT_FILENAME` fastcgi param and set it according to the location of your files.
> 4. In your nginx config file include `fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;` in the location block where all the other fastcgi params are defined.
> 5. In your php.ini set `cgi.fix_pathinfo` to `1`

Read more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23390531/access-denied-403-for-php-files-with-nginx-php-fpm?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: 1,2,3 = no,  4,5 = maybe

Comment: When I try to install via the command line I am getting the following error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory. [InvalidArgumentException] Parameter validation failed.